# Inputting a hash with default values

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I would like to initialize class with a the individual members of the hash set to default values, I have tried the following:

```
class SomeClass
  attr_accessor :hello, :holla
  def initialize ( hash = { hello: 'world', holla: 'mundo'})
    @hello = hash[:hello]
    @else = hash[:holla]
 end
end
```

which works as desired if do not input any argument

```
p = SomClass.new 
puts "should be 'world'"
puts p.hello
puts "should be 'mundo'"
puts p.holla

$ruby hello_world.rb
should be 'world'
universe
should be 'mundo'
mundo
```

but if one of the augments of the hash is set the other is left empty, for example:

```
p = SomeClass.new( { hello: 'universe'})
puts "should be 'universe'"
puts p.hello
puts "should be 'mundo'"
puts p.holla

$ruby hello_world.rb
should be 'universe'
universe
should be 'mundo'
```

How do I input hash as the argument for an initialization in manor that sets the default values for the individual members of the hash just the hash it self?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do this without custom code.  The simplest version of that would be:

```
def initialize(hash = {})
  hash = {hello: "world", holla: "mondo"}.merge(hash)
  # now your default values are set, but will be overridden by the passed argument
end
```

That will allow additional properties to be passed in the hash, but I assume that is desirable since you deliberately used an extensible input to start with.